# How can i undo my whole text being in italic in latex?

Tags: math-mode, italic

In Latex I have a simple formula and describe its variables underneath:

```
\[
    P_{ij} = \begin{cases}
            1, &         \text{if } \indent R_{ij} - O_{ij}\indent< 0\\
            0, &         \text{if } \indent R_{ij} - O_{ij} \indent $\geq$ 0
    \end{cases}

    with:
\]
\\
    \textit{R_{i}} = \text{Pre chat score given by person \textit{i} to question \textit{j}} 

   \noindent \textit{O_{i}} = \text{Post chat score given by person \textit{i} to question \textit{j}}
    \\
    \\
    \noindent \textit{j} \in $\{\textit{Questions on Suicidal Ideation or Risk Factors (See Table 1)}\}$

    \noindent \textit{i}  \in $\{\textit{Everyone that contacts 113, talks with a counselor and fills out both the pre- as well as the postchat questions}\}$
    \\
```

However, after I added the second part (start with 'with'), all the text in my paper is suddenly in italic. What can I change to my code, to undo this?

I've tried putting dollar signs around the different variables, however that makes my text disappear completely.

```
 \]
    \\
        $\textit{R_{i}} = \text{Pre chat score given by person \textit{i} to question \textit{j}} $

   $\noindent \textit{O_{i}} = \text{Post chat score given by person \textit{i} to question \textit{j}}$
    \\
    \\
    $\noindent \textit{j} \in \{\textit{Questions on Suicidal Ideation or Risk Factors (See Table 1)}\}$

    \noindent \textit{i}  \in \{\textit{Everyone that contacts 113, talks with a counselor and fills out both the pre- as well as the postchat questions}\}$
    \\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It will be easier to help you if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Please edit your question to add one, thanks.

Comment: If you get an error message please ask about the error and show the error message from the log file, after an error it is not usually worth looking at the pdf output except fro possibly debugging so asking just about the output iwithout mentioning that you had an error is misleading.

Comment: I didnt have an error, the output just wasn't what I wanted to be. But @Rmano gave a very helpful sugeestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have one of the `\textit{}` not balanced or one of the math in and out. But in my opinion the main problem is that is not LaTeX; you are trying to do visual editing (saying how do you want the output to **look**) and not semantic edit (saying what your text **is**). This is my proposal (although I am unsure about those `\in`...)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    P_{ij} = \begin{cases}
        1, &         \text{if $R_{ij} - O_{ij} < 0$}\\
        0, &         \text{if $R_{ij} - O_{ij} \geq 0$}
    \end{cases}
\]

with:

\begin{tabular}{cp{0.8\linewidth}}
    $R_{i}$:& Pre chat score given by person $i$ to question $j$ \\
    $O_{i}$:& Post chat score given by person $i$ to question $j$ \\
$j  \in$ & Questions on Suicidal Ideation or Risk Factors (See Table 1) \\
$i \in$ &Everyone that contacts 113, talks with a counselor and fills out both the pre- as well as the postchat questions\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]